# Open a second file after reader.onload()

Tags: javascript

I'm reading a file from an `<input type="file" />`

I'm using

```
onChange = (event) => {
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
        // I can read content and do some stuff and receibe another file "x.txt"
    }
}
```

And it's working the reading, but now I need to open the second file (x.txt), but I don't know how to launch the `.onload` or how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use another `FileReader`.

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (e) => {
    const reader2 = new FileReader();
    reader2.onload = e => {
    
    };
    reader2.readAsText( /* ... */ );
}
```

For reading a local file, you can use `fetch`.

```
const reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = (e) => {
    fetch("b.txt").then(res=> res.text())
       .then(text => console.log(text));
}
```

Comment: It says me "TypeError: Failed to execute 'readAsText' on 'FileReader': parameter 1 is not of type 'Blob'."  I'm passing it as a string.   reader2.readAsText("b.txt")

Comment: It's not reading the file and the file is on that route . url: "http://localhost:8080/b.txt"